# Add user and privileges and set password error

Tags: mysql

I have been tying to figure out why I cant add this user, I get the error msg. of bash: GRANT: command not found.

I've read other posts but cant seem to get past it, this is what I've been trying to run

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;

**ERROR:**

```
bash: GRANT: command not found.
```

Comment: **GRANT** is a mysql command, not a bash command.  Type in **mysql to see if its accessible.  if so, type the command after mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I was not in root sql folder when executing.

Fixed with:

sudo mysql -u root